Send emails that were redirected to database?
For a little while during troubleshooting we enabled the outbound e-mail option "redirect to database".  Now that troubleshooting is finished, we have changed the outbound email setting back to SMTP.  We now want those emails to be sent out.
I see the emails in civicrm_mailing_spool.  I've tried executing scheduled jobs relating to processing mailings and processing scheduled reminders.  But the emails remain in civicrm_mailing_spool.
Is there a way to trigger these emails to be sent?
Thank you!
PS: If it is a matter of moving the data to another database table manually, I know enough SQL to do that.  Hopefully just something I've missed because mucking around in the database is always scary but just wanted to call that out.

I had written a script to send mail from the spool, so probably you might need to do the same

@PradeepNayak if you want to turn your comment into an answer saying it's not possible without custom code, I'll mark as accepted.  Thank you for your help!

We had to write a script to send mails stored in Spool table, below is the code we used to send. You can add more filters to the query to restrict based on dates.
<?php
class CRM_HoldEmails_BAO_HoldEmails {

  /**
   *
   * Process emails from spool.
   *
   */
  public static function processEmailsFromSpool() {
    $mailerBatchLimit = self::getSettingValue('mailerBatchLimit');
    $sql = 'SELECT cms.* FROM `civicrm_mailing_spool` cms';
    if ($mailerBatchLimit) {
      $sql = " LIMIT {$mailerBatchLimit}";
    }
    $result = CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery($sql);
    while ($result->fetch()) {
      list($to, $header, $body) = self::createSendMailParams($result);
      $isSent = self::sendMail($to, $header, $body);
      if ($isSent) {
        self::deleteFromSpool($result->id, $result->job_id);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * Delete from spool once finished.
   *
   */
  public static function deleteFromSpool($spoolId, $jobId) {
    $count = CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery(
      "SELECT count(cm.id) FROM civicrm_mailing cm
        INNER JOIN civicrm_mailing_job cmj ON cmj.mailing_id = cm.id
        INNER JOIN civicrm_mailing_spool cms ON cms.job_id = cmj.id
        WHERE cm.is_completed = 1 AND cm.is_archived =1 AND cms.id = {$spoolId}
    ");
    if ($count == 1) {
      CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery(
        "DELETE cm.* FROM civicrm_mailing cm
          INNER JOIN civicrm_mailing_job cmj ON cmj.mailing_id = cm.id
          INNER JOIN civicrm_mailing_spool cms ON cms.job_id = cmj.id
          WHERE cm.is_completed = 1 AND cm.is_archived =1 AND cms.id = {$spoolId}"
      );
    }
  }

  /**
   *
   * process email params from spool.
   *
   */
  public static function createSendMailParams($result) {
    $to = explode(';', $result->recipient_email);
    $body = $result->body;
    $msgHeader = [];
    $headers = explode("\n", $result->headers);
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
      if (strpos($header, ': ') === FALSE) {
        $string .= "\n{$header}";
      }
      else {
        list($key, $string) = explode(': ', $header, 2);
      }

      $msgHeader[$key] = $string;
    }
    return [$to, $msgHeader, $body];
  }

  /**
   *
   * Send emails from spool.
   *
   */
  public static function sendMail($to, $headers, $message) {
    $mailer = \Civi::service('pear_mail');
    if (is_object($mailer)) {
      $errorScope = CRM_Core_TemporaryErrorScope::ignoreException();
      $result = $mailer->send($to, $headers, $message);
      if (is_a($result, 'PEAR_Error')) {
        return FALSE;
      }
      CRM_Utils_Hook::postEmailSend($params);
      return TRUE;
    }
  }

}



Thank you so much, Pradeep!
